# Updating related data in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

If I had a structure that looks like the below in firebase, how do I update the comment for a particular link

link1 node:

```
    {
  links: {
    link1: {
      title: "Example",
      href: "http://example.org",
      submitted: "user1",
      comments: {
        comment1: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment 1 node:

```
    comment1: {
  link: "link1",
  body: "This is awesome!",
  author: "user2"
}
```

I just need to update link1 by adding more comments, note that in real application, auto ids are generated for the nodes and makes it difficult to keep track of them. comment1 and link would be replace with auto generated ids.

----------------------------Edit----------------------------------------

Ok I have tried nesting the comments into the link so I can update the comment like this:

```
$scope.addComment = function(id){

  var cRef = $firebase(new Firebase("https://musicfs.firebaseio.com/comments"));
  var pRef = $firebase(new Firebase("https://musicfs.firebaseio.com/posts/"+id+"/comments"));
  var data = {body:$scope.commentBody, maker:Auth.$getAuth().facebook.displayName, post:id};  

  pRef.$push(data)

}
```

and that is all I have tried doing. But I dont have an idea at all on how I can isolate update the comments after isolating it from the links

------ EDit 2--------
I was able to put some code dowm:

```
$scope.addPost = function(){
    console.log($scope.category.name)
    var cat = ref.child('categories');
    var post = ref.child('posts');
    post.child($scope.post.title).set($scope.post)
    cat
    .child($scope.category.name)
    .child('posts')
    .set({$scope.post.title: 'true'});

  }
```

I just need to get the id of the last created post and set it to true in the category node.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If so, please show the code and explain where you stuck.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I have actually tried nothing because I don't know how to go about that and am new to firebase, but this is my little idea: I would insert(add) a comment and get the ld immediately. With the Id i can now do something like 'comment2:true' in the comments collection of a particular link but the problem is that when trying trying to do that it creates an id for comments by itself which does not reference the comment2 itself. Thanks

Comment: So you seem to have some code and have a problem making it do what you want. In that case, post the code you have, so we at least have some idea of where you're stuck.

Comment: Chis, it's unclear what you are expecting here. It seems like you're looking for a fundamental understanding of how to [create references](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-creating-references) and [save data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html), topics that are a bit broad for Q&A and already vigorously covered in [the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/).